# Execute powershell command with arguments from script

Tags: powershell, arguments

this is hashtable in my powershell script (data extracted using **Get-PSReadlineOption**):

```
$theme = @{}
$theme["CommentForegroundColor"] = "DarkGreen"
$theme["CommentBackgroundColor"] = "Black"
$theme["KeywordForegroundColor"] = "Green"
$theme["KeywordBackgroundColor"] = "Black"
```

I am trying to set powershell theme colors using **Set-PSReadlineOption** command:

```
foreach ($colorTokenKey in $theme.keys) {
    $c=$theme[$colorTokenKey]
    echo "$colorTokenKey will be set to $c"
    $colorTokenArgs = $colorTokenKey.Replace("ForegroundColor"," -ForegroundColor")
    $colorTokenArgs = $colorTokenArgs.Replace("BackgroundColor"," -BackgroundColor")
    $colorTokenArgs = $colorTokenArgs.Split(" ")
    $tokenKind = $colorTokenArgs[0]
    $tokenForegroundOrBackground = $colorTokenArgs[1]
    $params = "-TokenKind $tokenKind $tokenForegroundOrBackground $c"
    echo $params
    & Set-PSReadlineOption $params
}
```

But when I run this, I get

```
CommandBackgroundColor will be set to White
-TokenKind Command -BackgroundColor White
Set-PSReadlineOption : Cannot bind parameter 'TokenKind'. Cannot convert value "-Tok
enKind Command -BackgroundColor White" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.TokenClassifica
tion". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name -TokenKind Command -BackgroundCol
or White to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names a
nd try again:
None, Comment, Keyword, String, Operator, Variable, Command, Parameter, Type, Number
, Member"
At C:\Users\...\PowerShellColors.ps1:88 char:28
+     & Set-PSReadlineOption $params
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing all of your arguments as a *single* string, which is not what you want.

What you want to do is called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6).

Change your last lines to this:

```
$params = @{
    "TokenKind" = $tokenKind
    $tokenForegroundOrBackground = $c
}
Set-PSReadlineOption @params
```

Also, mind that you have to pass the parameters **without** the leading `-`! So you would have to change this too:

```
$colorTokenArgs = $colorTokenKey.Replace("ForegroundColor"," ForegroundColor")
$colorTokenArgs = $colorTokenArgs.Replace("BackgroundColor"," BackgroundColor")
```

(Or do maybe define it differently in the first place.)

A somewhat hacky alternative would be using [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6), which executes the string as a command:

```
Invoke-Expression "Set-PSReadlineOption $params"
```

Comment: Thank you! I would stumble into "splatting" (if stumble at all) in a long long time...

Comment: @Emil Just a heads-up: The syntax for this command has changed in the most recent PowerShell version. Keep this in mind if you want to update anytime soon, because you would have to change your script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-6

Comment: Ok, I will check. Thanks again!